# Timeout linux command behaviour

Tags: linux, timeout, gnu-coreutils

I was looking at linux `timeout` command.

Q1: Does `timeout` utility send signals to `childprocess` as well ?

Q2: Will it kill `childprocesses` if parent process exits before the timeout interval ?

i jumped between documentation but i wouldnt find a proper documentation for this behaviour.

**My Observations:**

i run the following script as `timeout 2s ./test.sh`

**test.sh**

```
 #!/bin/bash
(sleep 5; echo "Hello World") &
(sleep 5; echo "Hello World") &
(sleep 5; echo "Hello World") &
(sleep 5; echo "Hello World") &
```

here the `test.sh` exited before 2s therefore i think the timeout utility cannot kill the forked process and hence i saw the `hello world` after 5 sec

so does this mean that the timeout cannot kill the child process ?

Comment: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57667/why-cant-i-kill-a-timeout-called-from-a-bash-script-with-a-keystroke) answer, fantastic as usual by Gilles. Basically, `timeout` can kill child processes but only if they are not a member of a different process group than the one that `timeout` has created. In `Bash` `&` make a process run in the background and make it a member of a separate process group (see *Job Control* section in `man bash`). As you probably know, if you removed `&` then `Hello World` would not be printed even though it is executed in a subshell.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't due to separate process groups as this is a script and so not an interactive shell, job control is off. You can see this by adding this to the bottom of the script:

```
ps -o comm,pid,pgrp
```

The issue is that your script fires off the background tasks (in the same process group) but then exits. timeout(1) sees the exit and then exits itself. What you probably want to do is to get the script to wait for its background tasks to complete by adding a `wait` at the end.